# how to determine if generic list Tlist<t> is initilized or not

Tags: delphi

as i know when we want to check if an object initialized or not we can use isassigned, but at now i found it didn't work for generic list TList. isassigned return true all the time but it's wrong. so what is the solution?

Comment: Yes, it does work. What Delphi version are you using? Can you post some code? Don't confuse class members (which are always initialized) with local variables which are not initialized by default. Maybe your TList is a local variable? If you didn't do anything to it in the first place, then `Assigned(..)` obviously doesn't return `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object reference variable of type `TList<T>` is no different from any other object reference. You use `Assigned` with it just as you would any other object reference variable.

Note that `Assigned` can only test for initialization of object reference variables that have been initialized to `nil`.

For example, class instance members are initialized to `nil` before the instance's constructor starts to execute. Object references allocated with a call to `New` are initialized to `nil`. Or those set to the default value with an assignment to `Default()`.

But object reference variables that are local variables are not initialized to `nil`. In fact they are not initialized at all. Likewise for object reference variables that are allocated by a call to `GetMem`.

The bottom line is that the treatment of object reference variables of type `TList<T>` or indeed any other generic class, is identical to the treatment for any other `TObject` descendent.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm wrong. in c# it didn't work like that, both class members and local variables are null, thx man

Comment: Actually local variables in C# are not automatically initialized. You have to do it. However, if you try to read a local before initializing it, the compiler will gag.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi when you create an object it is initialized as part of constructing sequence.

It is not like ObjC `classname.alloc.init` where memory allocation and data initialization are split apart, in Delphi it all happens within `classname.Create` call.

So as long as you received object address fro mthe constructor - the object is both allocated and initialized.